# Thread Creation CPP

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have defined one thread function inside .cpp file and I have called createThread function to create thread it is working fine. If I declare thread function declaration in .h file and definition in .cpp file means the thread is not executing immediately the application quits. I'm creating a thread from main().what is the problem in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you definitely can. All you need is a handle to the created thread (`CreateThread()` returns that unless it fails). As long as you have the handle value *and* no part of your code has called `CloseHandle()` on that value you can use any waiting function.